# How to customize php artisan ui vue --auth files

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, registration

Good evening, I just want to ask, is it possible to edit the routes and other file that be generated when you run 
`php artisan ui vue --auth`

by customize I mean like, the registration is it possible to add steps in registering something like that, I just want to ask how, whenever I look at the routes/web.php theres no routes in registration but when I run php artisan route:list there is, sorry for asking and thank you in advance, have a nice day thank you

Comment: Yes you can override `Auth` Routes.

Comment: Can I ask how? or like add more in route/web.php , something like that

Comment: You need to remove the Auth Routes from your router file and then customize them at will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth::routes();` is a collection of routes. Which include routes:

```
// Authentication Routes
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

If you want to make changes on default auth files you can. You will find all the controllers in the Controllers/Auth directory and blade files in resources/Auth directory.

If you still find it hard. Instead of making changes in Laravel auth! You can just remove `Auth::routes();` from routes/web.php and create your own.

Here is an example:

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes
$this->get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes
$this->get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Its working, thank you so much sir for your help and idea how